# Create a Chart in dash-plot based on dropdown and date picker for a certain unique value

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, plot

I have a simple database as in the below picture:

[image]

and the query looks like:

```
SELECT 
       [Date]
      ,[eNodeBName]
      ,[Downlinkbandwidth]
      ,[DownlinkEARFCN]
      ,[CellName]
      ,[LocalCellId]
      ,[PhysicalcellID]
      ,[LRRCConnReqAtt]
      ,[RRCSetupSuccessRate]
      ,[InterFreqSuccessRate4G]
      ,[IntraRATHOSucccessRate]
      ,[IntraFreqSuccessRate4G]
      ,[CellDLMaxThroughputMbps]
      ,[CellDownlinkAverageThroughputMbps]
  FROM [myDB].[dbo].[input]
```

Now I need to create an interactive chart which depends on inputs like a date picker and drop down list.

As this is the sample GUI I created to figure chart throw this inputs as shown in the below picture:

[image]

Now I am creating chart based on the below columns name as in the below picture:

[image]

as this is the related query as the below:

```
SELECT 
       [Date]
      ,[CellName]
      ,[LRRCConnReqAtt]
      ,[RRCSetupSuccessRate]
      ,[InterFreqSuccessRate4G]
      ,[IntraRATHOSucccessRate]
      ,[IntraFreqSuccessRate4G]
      ,[CellDLMaxThroughputMbps]
      ,[CellDownlinkAverageThroughputMbps]
  FROM [myDB].[dbo].[input]
```

So now the X-axis should be the `Date` column and the y-axis related to those below columns is the `KPI` columns:

```
SELECT 
       [LRRCConnReqAtt]
      ,[RRCSetupSuccessRate]
      ,[InterFreqSuccessRate4G]
      ,[IntraRATHOSucccessRate]
      ,[IntraFreqSuccessRate4G]
      ,[CellDLMaxThroughputMbps]
      ,[CellDownlinkAverageThroughputMbps]
  FROM [myDB].[dbo].[input]
```

So now we have a unique column contains unique values is called `CellName`, this cell name I want create a simple chart for this unique value based on date columnn and KPI column.

So for example I want to show a line chart for a certain `CellName` = 2002334 for KPI `LRRCConnReqAtt` based on data from 27 of December to 9 of January. So I need a chart as the below picture and this is an example chart created in Excel.

[image]

and this is my code:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import datetime
from datetime import datetime as dt
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

# connect db
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://xxxxxx\SMxxxxxARTRNO_EXPRESS/myDB?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')
cursor = engine.raw_connection().cursor()

start = datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 2)
end = datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 15)

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

lte_kpis = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM [myDB].[dbo].[input]',
                       engine)

lte_kpis_raw = pd.read_sql('SELECT LRRCConnReqAtt, RRCSetupSuccessRate, InterFreqSuccessRate4G, IntraRATHOSucccessRate, IntraFreqSuccessRate4G,CellDLMaxThroughputMbps, CellDownlinkAverageThroughputMbps FROM [myDB].[dbo].[input]',
                           engine)

scale_1 = ['LRRCConnReqAtt']
scale_2 = ['RRCSetupSuccessRate', 'InterFreqSuccessRate4G', 'IntraRATHOSucccessRate', 'IntraFreqSuccessRate4G']
scale_3 = ['CellDLMaxThroughputMbps', 'CellDownlinkAverageThroughputMbps']

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

availble_cell = lte_kpis['CellName'].unique()

# availble_cell = lte_kpis.unique(lte_kpis[['Date', 'Site Name', 'Cell CI', 'Cell LAC']].values.ravel('K'))

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='cell-name-xaxis-column',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in availble_cell],
        value='2205516'
    ),

    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='myColumns',
        options=[{'label': col, 'value': col} for col in lte_kpis_raw.columns],
        multi=True,
        value='LRRCConnReqAtt'
    ),

    dcc.DatePickerRange(
        id='my-date-picker-range',
        min_date_allowed=dt(1995, 8, 5),
        max_date_allowed=dt(2030, 9, 19),
        initial_visible_month=dt(2019, 10, 5),
        start_date=dt(2019, 10, 1),
        end_date=dt(2020, 1, 1)
    ),
    html.Div(id='output-container-date-picker-range'),

    dcc.Graph(
        style={'height': 300},
        id='my-graph'
    )

])


@app.callback(
    Output('my-graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('cell-name-xaxis-column', 'value'),
     Input('myColumns', 'value')])
def update_graph(xaxis_column_name, yaxis_column_name, date_value):
    dff = lte_kpis[lte_kpis['Date'] == date_value]

    return {
        'data': [dict(
            x=dff[dff['Date'] == xaxis_column_name]['Value'],
            y=dff[dff['Date'] == yaxis_column_name]['Value'],
            text=dff[dff['Date'] == yaxis_column_name]['CellName'],
            mode='line',
            line={
                'size': 15,
                'opacity': 0.5
            }
        )],
    }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Note that I want to put more than one KPI in one chart with different plots....

As the scale values in those KPI are little bit different so I tried to create a three types of objects with columns name scale values as the below code

```
scale_1 = ['LRRCConnReqAtt']
scale_2 = ['RRCSetupSuccessRate', 'InterFreqSuccessRate4G', 'IntraRATHOSucccessRate', 'IntraFreqSuccessRate4G']
scale_3 = ['CellDLMaxThroughputMbps', 'CellDownlinkAverageThroughputMbps']
```

and this is the error I found:

```
TypeError: update_graph() missing 1 required positional argument: 'date_value'

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Users\mwx825326\PycharmProjects\MyReference\venv\Lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1337, in add_context
output_value = func(*args, **kwargs)  # %% callback invoked %%
TypeError: update_graph() missing 1 required positional argument: 'date_value'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mwx825326\PycharmProjects\MyReference\venv\Lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1337, in add_context
    output_value = func(*args, **kwargs)  # %% callback invoked %%
TypeError: update_graph() missing 1 required positional argument: 'date_value'
```

Any assistance appreciated.!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now this question is solved..

But I need it in more static way ,and the way I have to remove one `Drop-down` and create a chart based on one `Drop-down` and `Date-Picker` instead of 2 `Drop-down` as the removable drop down is based on Columns in `DB` in `y-axis`...

First I created Arrays for every Column should be the y-axis column, as I want to make it static charts for every multi or single Column in one Chart based on another Column or multiple Columns value in database....

as the below code:

```
SHOW_COLUMNS1 = [
    'lrrc_re_est_succ',
    'cell_dl_max_throughput'
]

SHOW_COLUMNS2 = [
    'interfreq_success_rate_4g',
    'intrarat_ho_success_rate'
]

SHOW_COLUMNS3 = [
    'rcc_setup_success_rate',
    'interfreq_success_rate_4g'
]

SHOW_COLUMNS4 = [
    'cell_downlink_average_throughput'
]
```

after that the connection to the `Date-Base`

```
# connect db
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://xxxxxx\zzzzzz/myDB?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')
cursor = engine.raw_connection().cursor()
lte_kpis = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM [myDB].[dbo].[lte_details]', engine)
```

after that I created a GUI for the interactive Charts and pandas read as the below code:

```
lte_kpis = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM [myDB].[dbo].[lte_details]', engine)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 10000)
print(lte_kpis)

lte_kpis.set_index('date', inplace=True)

availble_cell = lte_kpis['cell_name'].unique()

plots = []
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H5(
        'Huawei KPI Dashbord'),

    html.Label('Choose the "Cell-Name"'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='cell-name-xaxis-column',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in availble_cell],
        value= availble_cell[0]
    ),
    html.Label('Choose Date Destination'),
    dcc.DatePickerRange(
        id='date-picker-range',
        min_date_allowed=dt(1995, 8, 5),
        max_date_allowed=dt(2030, 9, 19),
        initial_visible_month=dt(2019, 10, 5),
        start_date=dt(2019, 10, 1),
        end_date=dt(2020, 1, 1)
    ),
    html.Div(id='output-container-date-picker-range-%s'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='yaxis-columns',
        options=[{'label': col, 'value': col} for col in SHOW_COLUMNS1],
        multi=True,
        disabled=True,
        value=[SHOW_COLUMNS1[0], SHOW_COLUMNS1[1]]
    ),
    dcc.Graph(
        style={'height': 300},
        id='my-graph'
    ),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='yaxis-columns2',
        options=[{'label': col, 'value': col} for col in SHOW_COLUMNS2],
        multi=True,
        disabled=True,
        value=[SHOW_COLUMNS2[0], SHOW_COLUMNS2[1]]
    ),
    dcc.Graph(
        style={'height': 300},
        id='my-graph2'
    ),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='yaxis-columns3',
        options=[{'label': col, 'value': col} for col in SHOW_COLUMNS3],
        multi=True,
        disabled=True,
        value=[SHOW_COLUMNS3[0], SHOW_COLUMNS3[1]]
    ),
    dcc.Graph(
        style={'height': 300},
        id='my-graph3'
    ),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='yaxis-columns4',
        options=[{'label': col, 'value': col} for col in SHOW_COLUMNS4],
        multi=True,
        disabled=True,
        value=[SHOW_COLUMNS4[0]]
    ),
    dcc.Graph(
        style={'height': 300},
        id='my-graph4'
    ),

])
```

and this is `Call-back`

```
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='my-graph2', component_property='figure'),
    [Input(component_id='cell-name-xaxis-column', component_property='value'),
     Input(component_id='yaxis-columns2', component_property='value'),
     Input(component_id='date-picker-range', component_property='start_date'),
     Input(component_id='date-picker-range', component_property='end_date')])
def update_graph(cell_name, yaxis_cols, start_date, end_date):
    if not isinstance(yaxis_cols, list):
        yaxis_cols = [yaxis_cols]
    print(yaxis_cols)
    print((start_date, end_date))

    sql_statement = "SELECT date, %s, %s FROM [myDB].[dbo].[lte_details] WHERE ([cell_name]='%s' AND [date]>='%s' AND [date]<='%s')" \
                    % (SHOW_COLUMNS2[0], SHOW_COLUMNS2[1], cell_name, start_date, end_date)
    df = pd.read_sql(sql_statement, engine)

    scatters = []

    for col in yaxis_cols:
        if col == 'lrrc_conn_req_att':
            scatters.append(go.Bar(
                x=df['date'],
                y=df[col],
                mode='lines',
                name=col
            ))
        else:
            scatters.append(go.Scatter(
                x=df['date'],
                y=df[col],
                name=col
            ))

    figure = {
        'data': scatters,
    }

    return figure
```

Note that as the previous error is related to the missing of data type in data base when importing the excel file to the data base related to the below Code:

```
col_dict = {
    'date': 'Date',
    'enodeb_name': 'eNodeB Name',
    'downlink_bandwidth': 'Downlink bandwidth',
          ...........................
}
LTE_DETAILS_TABLE = 'lte_details'

cols = list(col_dict.keys())

# connect db
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://xxxxx\xxxxxx/myDB?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')
connection = engine.connect()

meta = MetaData()
ltedetails = Table(
    LTE_DETAILS_TABLE, meta,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column(cols[0], Date),
    Column(cols[1], String),
    Column(cols[2], String),
       .................................
)

if engine.dialect.has_table(engine, LTE_DETAILS_TABLE):
    ltedetails.drop(engine)
meta.create_all(engine)

lte_df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'input.xlsx'), sheet_name='LTE Details', dtype={
    col_dict[cols[0]]: str,
    col_dict[cols[1]]: str,
    col_dict[cols[2]]: str,
        .....................................
})
lte_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(lte_df['Date'], errors='coerce')

query = db.insert(ltedetails)
values_list = []
row_count = 1
for i in lte_df.index:
    row = lte_df.loc[i]
    record = {'id': row_count}
    for col in col_dict.keys():
        if col == cols[3] or col == cols[4] or col == cols[5] or col == cols[6] or col == cols[7] or col == cols[8]:
            record[col] = int(row[col_dict[col]])
        elif col == cols[9] or col == cols[10] or col == cols[11] or col == cols[12] or col == cols[13] or col == cols[14]:
            record[col] = float(row[col_dict[col]])
        else:
            record[col] = row[col_dict[col]]
    values_list.append(record)
    row_count += 1

ResultProxy = engine.execute(query, values_list)

connection.close()
engine.dispose()
```

So I stuck now the I want to remove the `Dropp-down` with id ``which called `id='yaxis-columns',` ...

So If there's any comment about how to improve this code performance and Complete to solve my issue..

I am glad for that.